# obtener un rango de datos en Visual Basic

Tags: vb

Quisiera Obtener un rango de datos en la función de visual basic, es decir tengo 1000 datos pero solo quiero obtener la cantidad de 100 datos, este es mi código en Visual Basic y quisiera saber la forma de obtener la cantidad de datos, de esta manera obtengo todo los datos que tengo almacenado en sql pero quisiera solo obtener cierta cantidad

```
 Public Function Datos(ByVal NoFact As String) As DataTable

    Try
        Dim dtResultado As New DataTable
        Dim sqladap As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()


        If Todas = True Then
            Dim sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SP_Example")
            sqlcon.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlcon.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            sqladap.SelectCommand = sqlcon
            sqladap.Fill(dtResultado)

            If dtResultado.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Return dtResultado
            Else
                Return New DataTable

            End If
```

Comment: ¿Quieres realizar una paginación?. En caso quieres realizar la paginación, ¿Quieres realizarlo a nivel de tu función `Datos` o de tu procedimiento almacenado `SP_Example`?. Debes comprender que es recomendable a nivel de BD.

Comment: @Davilo no quiero realizar ninguna paginación, solo quiero obtener la cantidad de datos del `SP_Example` , así obtengo la cantidad de 1000 datos pero solo quiero obtener 100 datos o 200.

Comment: Lo quieres mostrar de a 100 desde el server? quieres traer los 1000 y localmente quieres mostrarlo de a 100?

Comment: @Luis Mata así es,en el server tengo 1000 datos pero solo quiero mostrar 100 datos localmente, sin modificar el Stored procedure

Comment: si quieres intervalos de 100, mínimo tu SP debe de recibir 2 parámetros desde y hasta, y suponer que en tu tabla tienes un ID para controlar eso, lo otro seria que tu SP cree una vista en donde si tengas un ID y manipular la vista.

Answer (score 0):

En el Query puedes definir la cantidad de datos a obtener:

```
Dim query As String = "select top 100 * from table"
Dim sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query)
```

Si usas un Stored Procedure, simplemente modificalo usando "select top 100 * from table" para obtener únicamente los datos que deseas.

```
   Dim sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("nombre_stored_procedure")
            sqlcon.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlcon.Connection = con
            con.Open()
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: gracias por tu comentario pero no estoy usando una simple consulta, estoy usando un Stored procedure, por eso mi duda de cómo obtener cierta cantidad de datos del stored procedure

Comment: @Daniel en el caso de un SP modificalo usando select top 100 * ... para que obtengas la cantidad de datos requerida.

Comment: y no se puede obtener la cantidad de datos localmente sin la necesidad de modificar el Stored procedure

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: @Daniel de hecho puede ser como lo realizas " If dtResultado.Rows.Count < 100 Then", ¿ pero que sentido tiene realizar esto si el Stored Procedure por ejemplo pudo obtener 10000 resultados? lo correcto sería realizarlo desde el SP.

Comment: ya lo había hecho de esa manera pero me dice que no se encontraron archivos, aquí el problema es cuando no quieren que modifiques el stored procedure, es decir que ellos te dan el Stored procedure y yo solo debo consumirlo.